# Custom HTTP status codes from AppEngine Java endpoints

Tags: google-app-engine, rest, google-cloud-endpoints, http-status-codes

Everyone loves REST-fulness, so I'd like to return the most appropriate HTTP status codes from my AppEngine endpoints. Like 201 CREATED, for example, when a resource has been created.

But I can't find how to do this with GAE Java endpoints.

Some 4xx codes are supported by throwing an exception (NotFoundException causes a 404, for example), but that's not an appropriate solution for 2xx codes.

Can anyone help please?

Matthew

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Endpoints does support creating your own Custom Exception classes by subclassing `com.google.api.server.spi.ServiceException`

However, from the documentation at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/exceptions , it is mentioned that HTTP 2xx codes should not be used in custom exception classes.

Comment: Indeed, that's what I said in my question ;-)
And even if I did go the `ServiceException` route, I wouldn't then be able to return XML/JSON content in the response body.